# Getting JS Slider Page Number

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have a slider that is grouped like this:

```
<div>
    <div>slide content</div>
    <div>slide content</div>
    <div>slide content</div>
    <div>slide content</div>
    <div>slide content</div>
</div>
<div>
    <div>slide content</div>
    <div>slide content</div>
    <div>slide content</div>
    <div>slide content</div>
    <div>slide content</div>
</div>
...
```

Each top-level div is a "page." The slidered is grouped every 5 slides and shows 5 at a time.

What I need to do is programmatically figure out what "page" a slide is on.

So I can get the current index of a slide, example is 6 (the slider's index Method is 0 based). I need to then move the slider to page 2. Likewise if a slide's index is 10, it would be page 3.

I do not need help moving the slider, I just cannot figure out how to get the slider page to move to from just the slide's index.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Yes, all the formulas I came up with return unsuccessful results. I guess I am at a roadblock and am looking for some advice.

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted the JavaScript you tried to your question. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe try something like: `var page = (((index + 1) % 5) == 0) ? ((index + 1) / 5) : Math.floor((index + 1) / 5) + 1;` I think this should give the the 1-based page number.

Comment: @jwatts1980 you got it man. Make an answer so I can accept! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
var page = (((index + 1) % 5) == 0) ? ((index + 1) / 5) : Math.floor((index + 1) / 5) + 1;
```

I think this should give the the 1-based page number.

Comment: Thanks, just want I needed!